# Android: Change absolute position of a view programmatically

Tags: android, runtime, position, absolutelayout

If you use an AbsoluteLayout (I know that it is deprecated, but it was the only way to solve my  [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438656/android-scrollable-horizontal-and-vertical-imageview-with-buttons-overlayed)) you can give the childViews the tag `android:layout_x` and `android:layout_y` to set their absolute position within the `AbsoluteLayout`.

However I don't want to set these information in the xml, because I only know them at runtime. So how can I set these parameters at runtime programmatically? I don't see any method on the View like `view.setLayoutX(int x)` or something.

Here is my XML, which works fine, when I set the `layout_x` and `layout_y` values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/myImageView"
     android:layout_width="1298px"
     android:layout_height="945px"
     android:layout_x="0px"
  android:layout_y="0px" />
 <Button  
  android:id="@+id/myButton1"
  android:text="23"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_x="50px"
  android:layout_y="300px"
  android:tag="23"/>


 <Button  
  android:id="@+id/myButton2"
  android:text="48"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_x="50px"
  android:layout_y="300px"
  android:tag="48"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

In fact, I don't want to set any button within the xml anymore, but rather retrieve some information via remote and add buttons depending on that information.

Here is the part the code I'm using so in my `onCreateMethod` to add these buttons:

```
  for (MyRemoteObject remoteObject: list)  {
   Button button = new Button(this);
   button.setOnClickListener (listener);
   button.setTag(remoteObject.id);
   button.setText(remoteObject.id);
   // button.setLayoutX(remoteObject.x) ????
   // button.setLayoutY(remoteObject.y) ????
   myLayout.addView(button);
  }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the version of addView that takes [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.html):

```
LayoutParams params = mLayout.generateLayoutParams();
params.x = remoteObject.x;
params.y = remoteObject.y;
mLayout.addView(button, params);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how how can i create LayoutParams given that mLayout is of Type AbsoluteLayout? AbsoluteLayout only has a method absolutLayout.generatelayoutParams(AttributeSet). I dont know how to create an attributeSet in the first place so that I can pass that set to the generateLayoutParams()-Method

Comment: I have the same problem with a RelativeLayout instead of Absolute

Comment: `params.x` and `params.y` seems like they are deprecated for `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 10):

In response to your comment on Mayra's answer, I had a similar issue with RelativeLayout instead of AbsoluteLayout. The solution was to use a similar method and cast it as your layout type. Something like this:

```
LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) this.generateDefaultLayoutParams();
params.height = 360;
params.width = 360;
params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT);
this.addView(board, params);
```

It took me forever to figure this out so I wanted to post it here for someone else if they needed it.

Answer (score 5):

I had just the same problem but found a somewhat different solution.

```
int width = 100, height = 50, x = 10, y = 20;
Button button = new Button(this);
AbsoluteLayout myLayout = (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
myLayout.add(button, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y));
```

And if you find out what to use for "fill_parent" (hint try -1) then you may use those constants for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when moving top and left edges the Android keeps the right and bottom edges in same place. As I could not change the width and height properly (the image was disappearing), I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android/):

```
LayoutParams layoutParams=new LayoutParams(width, height);
layoutParams.leftMargin = newLeft;
layoutParams.topMargin = newTop;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I don't know if it's the best way, but worked for me. I've tested it in 2.2+ and works fine!

You must import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams; because the default is ViewGroup's LayoutParams (by [Davit T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770452/david-t))

Answer (score 0):

the above  answers are right.but this one would be more perfect

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,DragLayer.int left_location,int top_location);
 layout.addView(view,layoutParams)
```