# Change absolute position with FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I has a View that should be displayed at a specific position over some images, I already did that using AbsoluteLayout, but I don't want to use it and I'm trying to get the same result with a FrameLayout.

But I can't get this working, this is my two attempts:

```
public void showVideo(RectF bounds) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) video.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) bounds.width();
    params.height = (int) bounds.height();
    int x = (int) viewer.getPageXOffset();
    int y = (int) viewer.getPageYOffset();

    video.setPadding((int) (x + bounds.left), (int) (y + bounds.top), (int) (x + bounds.right),
            (int) (y + bounds.bottom));

    video.setLayoutParams(params);
    video.invalidate();

    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setFocusable(true);
    video.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    video.requestFocus();
}
```

And:

```
public void showVideo(RectF bounds, final String videoUrl) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) video.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) bounds.width();
    params.height = (int) bounds.height();
    int x = (int) (viewer.getPageXOffset() + bounds.left);
    int y = (int) (viewer.getPageYOffset() + bounds.top);

    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;

    video.setLayoutParams(params);
    video.invalidate();

    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setFocusable(true);
    video.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    video.requestFocus();
}
```

But in both cases, the VideoView are displayed at v(0,0) (left-top corner).

Comment: Is it necessary for you to create the layout in dynamically in code? I've never had this kind of problems when working with FrameLayout in XML

Comment: Actually, I need to show just one View that appears on top of the current (without AbsoluteLayout) at a specific position, and this position are calculated on runtime.

Comment: also see `view.setTranslationX()` or `view.offsetLeftAndRight()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should work when you set up gravity in LayoutParams.

Try

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

for a start.