# Add a Textview to a FrameLayout in a determined position

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

I'm trying to add a `textView` to a `frameLayout`. The `TextView` has `wrap_content` properties, so it grows when the text grows. I'm adding it to a `FrameLayout` with this function:

```
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).addView(mEditText);
```

---

This is the xml of the frame layout:

```
<FrameLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
</FrameLayout>
```

The textView always appears in the top left corner of the screen. I'd like to position it in the middle, or top middle. How can this be done?
I looked over the answers in [How can I dynamically set the position of view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android) and they weren't much help :( Mainly caused crashes..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).addView(mEditText, params);
```

Change [Gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) to suit your need.

BTW, the frame layout should use `fill_parent` for width and height

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that worked!!
Changing the frame layout to fill_parent ruins stuff for me, it doesn't show the views that are under this view.

Comment: instead of fill_parent better to use match_parent.

Comment: You might also use `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for `width` property in case your textview has a small text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to gravity or Layout gravity to your Framelayout or the Textview. It makes your Layout to the center of the screen. Use like this,

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: doesn't help, he need to insert dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you can try it by set the gravity of text use it like-

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.center);
```

othervise by `xml` set gravity to center so it will display you in center and if you'll use `centerinparents` so it will always apperas at the center of screen.

Comment: Doesn't work. The view still appears at the top left, but the cursor is now in the middle of the view

Answer (score 0):

Set `FrameLayout` properties `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `fill_parent` and also set `TextView` property `LayoutGravity` . such as `Center`, `Right` or `Top`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your frame layout

```
<FrameLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" > 
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the gravity programatically definitely works
Please set the layout_gravity to right in the xml
    TextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);