# How to change Android Framelayout Positioning on Run Time?

Tags: android, position, android-framelayout

I want to change the position of my framelayout on click of a button. Can anyone suggest me the best way to do this?

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Check the answer at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android