# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT make ImageView smaller in loop

Tags: android, android-layout

I add ImageView to layout in runtime, But ImageView is smaller after every loop. This is my code:

```
    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(
    for(int i=0; i< fruit.size();i++) {
        int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(i).file, "drawable",
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        int h = random.nextInt(height);
        int w = random.nextInt(width);
        Logger.debug(TAG, "drawable/"+fruit.get(i).file+":"+id+":X="+w+":Y="+h);
        ImageView imageView =new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(id);
        imageView.setScaleX(0.3f);
        imageView.setScaleY(0.3f);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(w,h,0,0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        layout.addView(imageView);
```

And this is my result:
[image]

Please help me why and how to fix it?
Thank you very much

More information: 
If I replace code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(w,h,0,0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

By

```
imageView.setY(h);
imageView.setX(w);
```

Result will [image]

Answer (score 1):

may be this create problem

```
layoutParams.setMargins(w,h,0,0);
```

setmargin put margin as 
setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

Comment: You're right, this is cause of problem, Do you know how to set position of ImageView instead use setMargins?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android.Or else try to set padding for layout layout.setPadding(0,padding,0,0); It will have same effect as margin.

Comment: I used setX(), setY() and this is result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IzEcW.png. It always have a large space from left and top screen. I don't know why?

Comment: may be that margin is from layout ,have a look

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the Random class. You are already bounding the random number. You can shift the generated number, if you don't want it to approach to zero.

```
int h = random.nextInt(height) + height;
```

Or you can change the seed if you are providing any. Please see the link below.

[How the random numbers are calculated.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Comment: h and w only used for margin, if use your code, every object will fly out of screen