# Add a child view to a parent layout with the same bounds

Tags: android, android-layout

In a `RelativeLayout` I have 2 buttons: `button` and `button2`. These 3 itself lie inside the root view which is also a `RelativeLayout`.

What I am trying to accomplish here is that when `button` is clicked `button2` should be removed from the inner `RelativeLayout`(its id is `otherLayout`) and get added to the root `View` which is `rootView` but with the same bounds as it was in the inner layout.

Here is my XML and Java code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    tools:context="com.test.testproject.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/otherLayout"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
            android:text="One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:text="Two" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button,button2;

    int mLeft,mRight,mTop,mBottom;
    RelativeLayout otherLayout;
    RelativeLayout rootView;
    ViewGroup childParent;
    int[] mBounds = new int[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
//        rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        otherLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.otherLayout);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Rect r = new Rect();

                button2.getLocalVisibleRect(r);
//                button2.getDrawingRect(r);
//                ((ViewGroup)button2.getParent()).offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(button2, r);

                mLeft = r.left;
                mRight = r.right;
                mBottom = r.bottom;
                mTop = r.top;

                childParent = (ViewGroup) button2.getParent();


                ((ViewGroup)button2.getParent()).removeView(button2);

                Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        button2.setTop(mTop);
                        button2.setLeft(mLeft);
                        button2.setBottom(mBottom);
                        button2.setRight(mRight);

/*
                        button2.setX(mBounds[1]);
                        button2.setY(mBounds[0]);*/


                        ((ViewGroup)rootView).addView(button2);
                    }
                },1000);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I tried a different methods but would work. I used `getLocalVisibleRect()`, `getDrawingRect()` and all (You can see in the commented code).

So how do I achieve this? Remember, that the requirement is that the `View` residing in the inner layout and after adding to root should have the same bounds and params and the position on screen also must not change.

Comment: I didn't get it, why do you want your button to move outside the RelativeLayout if you don't want the UI to change?

Comment: What's the purpose of that? Clarify the use-case.

Comment: @Eselfar - All I want to do is to actually overlay the target `View` above the layout.So that the View's position doesn't look as if it has changed. After that I will perform a zoom animation which will draw this view above the other views. I tried to do the same with `clipChildren` to `false` but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: @azizbekian Please see my above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue may be with the layout parameters of `button2`. Probably the easiest way to approach this is to capture the position of `button2` in the layout and set up new layout parameters. `mLeft` and `mTop` to be the left and top margins.

A simplified `onCreate` method is below, but I am curious about why this would be useful.

Also take a look at [these caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678910/6287910). The document for `View` specifies why `setTop`, etc. should not be called outside the layout system. (See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTop(int)).)

> **setTop**
>
> void setTop (int top)
>
> Sets the top position of this view relative to its parent. This method is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be called otherwise, because the property may be changed at any time by the layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button button;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    otherLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.otherLayout);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
            int top = button2.getTop();
            int left = button2.getLeft();

            ((ViewGroup) button2.getParent()).removeView(button2);
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
            button2.setLayoutParams(params);
            rootView.addView(button2);
        }
    });
}
```