# View and imagery consistently bordering each other instead of overlapping as it should?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Brief, bulletin point description of my problem:

- Tried to move a view to new location and clickable.
- Failed because only the imagery (image + text) moved to the new location while view itself programactically stayed behind.
- Will fire ClickListener events only if original location instead of new location were clicked
- Attempt to move view to the same location with the following code:

  ```
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

          ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams constraintLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) swipeGridMenu.getLayoutParams();
          constraintLayoutParams.leftMargin = 548; 
          swipeGridMenu.setLayoutParams(constraintLayoutParams);

      }
  ```
- End result resembles the following, nothing like purposed:
  [image]
- Both imagery and view moves as parameter changes, the 2 simply border each other instead of properly overlapping and aligned.
- Both setFillAfter and setFillEnabled were set to true.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand your problem but It seems you are misunderstanding how animation works. The animation is a graphic representation but do not change the reactive area of the UI elements. Could it be this your problem?

Comment: You are absolutely right but that's not the point at this moment.

Comment: The point is that I want to move my reactionary area to a new area, THE SAME EXACT area of the imagery, but failed to find the proper way to do so, at least constraintLayoutParams.leftMargin = xxx; doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android. Remember to set the type of the parameters based on the layout inside which your inner elements are located. I think your case is ConstraintLayout.