# RecyclerView with action button as the last element, but It float or stick at bottom when there is many items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

what I want to implement is a screen where I have RecyclerView that shows a list .. it may has many or few items, when it has many items the Button must be floating and sticky at the end of the screen.

and if the items are few, where there is an empty space in the screen, the button must appear as the final element in the RecyclerView list.

the button is a rectangular raised button with a background. is there any suggestion how to achieve something like this.

Comment: That's a strange design. What if instead you do a floating button same way as done in GMail and many other apps? That would be in accordance to Google guidelines.

Comment: well if I have the choice, I wouldn't be here  :D .. this is the Business requirement

Answer (score 1):

doing like that

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

That's the result when has many item

[image]

and when has few item

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight_sum ="10">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"/>
        <Button
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is same as answer above. But difference is that the button will be always aligned at the bottom with weight 1.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the button floating the whole time above the list view, and position it manually to make it appear to be at the bottom of the list. if you control the position you can determine when it should stick at the bottom.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime) post on how to get the height of an view at runtime.

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

int height=view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels) article for how to get the screen height

```
int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

then in your layout.xml you can put

```
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the element
```

then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android) information to position the button

and now the magic happens

```
int offset = screenHeight - ButtonHeight - listHeight;
if(offset < 0) offset = 0;
btn.setTop(offset);
```