# Move view hiding its side in android

Tags: android-animation

Moving a view I try to hide all parts of view that cross some vertical line, so view starts to loose its width to 0.
The image describes better what I want.
I mean not just shrink a width with `scaleX` but hide, because this command compresses the photo horizontally, and I need to hide it without distortion.

How can I do it?

[image]

On the image a photo started to move left with `translationX` hiding line by line left side of the photo during this movement. Also, the photo is not at left edge of screen - it's on the center

Answer (score 0):

View has left(and x) attribute in its LayoutParams.

[How can I dynamically set the position of view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android)

When left attribute is negative, it is hidden under the parent view.

If you want an animation, here is the document!

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/reposition-view

Comment: it's not about positioning or resizing a view. Why you posted it as it obviously cannot help?

Comment: If you set `left` attribute to negative, you can hide it under the parent view.

Comment: I added what I just commented! Sorry for incomplete answer.