# Random TextView position

Tags: android, android-layout, random, textview

I'm trying to display a `TextView` in random positions on the screen, but the text shouldn't go outside the screen.  The text will always be short, no more than 3 words.  This is what I have so far:

```
        final TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        final Random rand = new Random();
        final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = rand.nextInt(metrics.widthPixels);
        int height = rand.nextInt(metrics.heightPixels);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams flp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        flp.setMargins(width, height, 0, 0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(flp);
```

UPDATE:

Forgot, I had this function to get a random number within a range:

```
public static int Random(final int lower, final int uppper)
{
    return lower + (int)(Math.random() * ((uppper - lower) + 1));
}
```

So I updated the code to this:

```
        int width = Random(0, metrics.widthPixels);
        int height = Random(0, metrics.heightPixels);
```

But it still sometimes displays outside the viewing area.  I even subtracted 10 from each value, to ensure it stays in.  For the most part it does, but then it seems like it shows somewhere outside the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try looking up abit more on getting the random number to stay inside the max width and height,

Comment: Actually, it helped a little, because I forgot had a function to get a random number within a range.  Updated my OP with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you do this?

Instead of doing that, you can found the Max x and Max y for the device and then Based on condition you can set the View's position to perticular position.

Also see this: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441475/android-change-absolute-position-of-a-view-programmatically)

might be helpful to you.

comment me for any query.

Comment: What is the difference between that and what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

> but it still sometimes displays outside the viewing area

1. Dont you have title on top of your activity? That does count in... Am not sure but I think the notification bar as well... If u work in fullscreen mode, you shouldnt have problem.
2. Remember that the x y coordinates are always the upper left corner of an objectview! So it still can be happen that u get half (or full in case :D) of your picture/textview/whatever outside the screen...